# PHP return values from Wordpress within loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return, var

I'm having some trouble returning values from a function. The function itself contains a loop that gets, and assigns, a bunch of variables from a wordpress blog. What I want to do is return the variables defined in the loop so I can simply echo them elsewhere. I need to run the same loop, but with different parameters, multiple times so they need to be inside functions to prevent any issues.

I'm using wordpress as a CMS - the file will eventually be included and the variables returned will be echo'd to populate the content of the site.

Here is my code:

```
function recentFeatured3(){

    $args = array( 'category' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_status' =>  'publish', 'order' => 'DESC' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        $count++;

        ${'featured_title' . $count}=$recent["post_title"];
        ${'featured_post_id' . $count}=$recent["ID"];

        ${'featured_post_' . $count} = get_post(${'featured_post_id' . $count}); 
        ${'featured_content' . $count} = ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_content;
        ${'featured_date' . $count} = mysql2date('F j, Y', ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_date);
        ${'featured_excerpt' . $count} = substr(${'featured_content' . $count},0,160).'...';

    }

    return $featured_title1;
    return $featured_title2;
    return $featured_post_id1;
    return $featured_post_id2;
    return $featured_content1;
    return $featured_content2;
    return $featured_date1;
    return $featured_date2;
    return $featured_excerpt1;
    return $featured_excerpt2;

}

echo $featured_title1; //and so on....
```

As you can see, I just want to echo the variables defined and created from the loop outside of the function. I'm not sure if the return needs to go inside the loop - I've tried both inside, and outside, and neither works. The variable is being named based off the count of the loop also, so I'm not sure how to work around that or if that is causing the problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a whole slew of pieces of information, you can't do that with multiple `return` statements. Only the first gets executed and the rest are dead code. What you need to do is create a collection of some kind (typically in PHP an Object or Array), put all the data in that single thing, and then return (a reference to) that single thing.
Furthermore, you want a collection of collections! For each post, a set of values, and there will be multiple posts. Here's an example of how that might look, returning an array of arrays:

```
function recentFeatured3(){
$resultsArray = array(); // you can just write '[]' in PHP >= 5.4

$args = array( 'category' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_status' =>  'publish', 'order' => 'DESC' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    $postInfo = array();
    $postInfo['featured_title'] = $recent["post_title"];
    $postInfo['featured_post_id'] = $recent["ID"];
    $postInfo['featured_post'] = get_post(${'featured_post_id' . $count}); 
    $postInfo['featured_content'] = ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_content;
    $postInfo['featured_date' = mysql2date('F j, Y', ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_date);
    $postInfo['featured_excerpt'] = substr(${'featured_content' . $count},0,160).'...';
    array_push($resultsArray, postInfo);
}

return $resultsArray;
}

$results = recentFeatured3();
foreach($results as $index=>$postInfo) {
    echo "results for post #".$index;
    foreach($postInfo as $key=>$value) {
         echo $key . " has value " . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution but I can't get it to validate. I posted my code up top.

Comment: there was a small typo. missing a ']'. nevermind! I'll see how this works out.

Comment: I still can't get anything from the array to echo outside the function. if I do `print_r` inside the function I can see that everything is working. Doesn't seem to be returning anything for some reason.

Comment: To print the results, you need to take the array that was returned to you and iterate through the elements of it. I'll add some sample code.

Comment: thanks a million. works beautifully! I've never really created my own arrays before but now I understand them a whole lot better.

Comment: this way be a stupid question, but how do I isolate the specific values and assign them as variables?

Comment: not stupid at all! `$featured_title_1 = $results[0]['featured_title']`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple returns like that. Only the first one is executed. Collect your values in an array.

```
function recentFeatured3(){

  $args = array( 'category' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_status' =>  'publish', 'order' => 'DESC' );
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
  $data = array();
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

    $count++;

    $data['featured_title' . $count}=$recent["post_title"];
    $data['featured_post_id' . $count}=$recent["ID"];

    $data['featured_post_' . $count] = get_post(${'featured_post_id' . $count}); 
    $data['featured_content' . $count} = ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_content;
    $data['featured_date' . $count} = mysql2date('F j, Y', ${'featured_post_' . $count}->post_date);
    $data['featured_excerpt' . $count} = substr(${'featured_content' . $count},0,160).'...';

  }

  return $data

}

echo $data['featured_title1']; //and so on....
```

Comment: You have a typo in the initialization of $data. I think the array of arrays in my answer makes it much easier to get out the info you want later than fabricating array index names with a numeric suffix, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` more than 1 time so you should replace to

```
$arr = array();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    $post = array();
    $post['featured_title']=$recent["post_title"];
    $post['featured_post_id']=$recent["ID"];
    $featuredPost = get_post($recent["ID"]); 
    $post['featured_post'] = $featuredPost; 
    $post['featured_content'] = $featuredPost->post_content;
    $post['featured_date'] = $featuredPost->post_date);
    ${'featured_excerpt' . $count} = substr($post['featured_content'],0,160).'...';
    $arr[] = $post;
}

    return $arr;
}

print_r(recentFeatured3());
```